# Error making Ajax call using https to webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, https

I am converting a web application to https and have hit a strange problem

A page (within the same website) is requested using https
The webmethod is called via Ajax with https
When returning a locally defined object all works fine.

```
  public class Thing
    {
        public string message { get; set; }

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static Thing Test(object data)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy  = new MyPolicy();
        Thing thing = new Thing { message = "ok" };
        return thing;
    }
```

However if the returned object is defined in an external DLL - the calls fails, in fact doesn't even arrive in the webmethod - no error on the ajax call and no data returned.

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static ExternalDLL.Thing Test1(object data)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();
        ExternalDLL.Thing thing = new ExternalDLL.Thing{ message = "ok" };
        return thing;

    }
```

If these calls are made using http then everything works as expected. Should I be doing something with the referenced DLL ?